# inject node modules files into index.html

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection, gulp, bower

I am using bower & npm as package manager to handle dependencies. now the bower is showing

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! 
Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: 
https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
```

So i have integrated `yarn` using `bower-away`. Now all the bower dependencies are moved into my package.json as like below

```
"@bower_components/angular": "angular/bower-angular#~1.6.4",
"@bower_components/jquery": "jquery/jquery-dist#>= 1.9.1"
```

I used `wiredep` to inject all the dependency libraries into index.html. It will automatically handle bower dependencies. 
Now i have removed `bower` completely so this won't work. 
Is there any other method to move dependencies into index.html. currently I am using `gulp inject` method to inject all the files like as below `.pipe(inject(gulp.src(["./src/*.js", "./src/*.css"], {read: false}))` but it's not handling for all packages.  because path is completely different.
For Ex: jquery and angular folder like as below

[image]

can anyone suggest is there any other method to achieve this.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

you still able to fix it using `gulp inject`:

```
gulp.task('injectfiles', function () {

    var appJS= ["./src/*.js"];// pattern to match your files

    var  libJS= [           
                '(path where jquery exist)/jquery.js',
                '(path where angular exist)/angular.js'
                ];

          var  jsOrder= [
                '**/jquery.js',
                '**/angular.js',
                '(rest lib js)'
                '**/app.module.js',
                '**/*.module.js',
                '**/*.constants.js',
                '**/*.value.js',
                '**/*.config.js',
                '**/*.route.js',
                '**/*.filter.js',
                '**/*.service.js',
                '**/*.controller.js',
                '**/*.directive.js',
                '**/*.js'
            ];

         var src = [].concat(libJS,appJS)


        return gulp
        .src('index path')
        .pipe(inject(src, '', jsOrder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest path'))
})



function inject(src, label, order) {
    //  var options = { read: false };
    var options = {}
    if (label) {
        options.name = 'inject:' + label
    }

    return $.inject(orderSrc(src, order), options)
}


function orderSrc(src, order) {
    // order = order || ['**/*'];
    return gulp
        .src(src)
        .pipe($.if(order, $.order(order)))
}
```

Comment: I have updated the above code, but i am getting below error `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular-cookies.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular-ui-router.min.js:1`

Comment: `libJS` contain all library that you need in your website, as i sww from exception you depend also on `angular-cookies.min.js` `angular-ui-router.min.js` ... etc, so do add all of them in this array...
also `jsOrder` is to specify orders for all `js` to be inject in  the `index.html`, so again you need to specify all `lib js` in correct order (as you see in first three lines from `jsOrder` array)...
in this way it should work for sure... 
keep in mind `webpack` as better a solution.

Comment: after injecting i can see the files are injected as index.html file. I can't open the js files in browser by viewing inspect element.